# Puzzling Sequence

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Today I was given a question that first I thought might be easy to solve but then no matter how hard I tried I couldn't solve it.(It's not really related to maths just some puzzle)

if:

$$
9999=4\\
8888=8\\
6181=3\\
1212=0
$$

Then: 
$$
1991=?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many closed loops in the number?

Comment: closed loops?Sorry I didn't get that :/

Comment: Interpret the number symbols as curves.

Comment: WOW! Brilliant Idea!!!

Comment: @FuriousMathematician He means holes.